# Magento configurable product displayed as simple in backend

Tags: php, magento, configurable-product, magento-1.9

Magento version 1.9.1.0.

I've added attributes to a set. Some are applied to the simple product type and others to the configurable type.

When I create a new configurable product. I successfully got the correct attributes in the backend form. But once saved, the form renders only simple attributes on this configurable product.

The project is working on version 1.8.1.0. I've tried to disable all local modules but I keep getting this misconfiguration.

Database analysis show that all of SQL records are similar to the 1.8 database. No cache enabled. Cache folders cleaned.

Even a hint would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Attributes that you selected to use for configurable product are not included within standard tabs while editing product.

Those attributes should be displayed on **"Associated Products" tab** of **Edit product form** for configurable product.

You should create simple products with different values of those (configurable) attributes and link them to your configurable product (creation as well as linking can be performed on mentioned tab).